# OpenVPN Server to OpenVPN Server Communication

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have two cloud servers in the same Digital Ocean data center with internal communication enabled (they can ping each other). Each cloud server has an OpenVPN server installed.

My question is how can I pass data from client A through vpn server A across the internal ip space through vpn server B to client B and vice versa? I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04 on both cloud servers and clients.

[image]

[*Thank you draw.io*](https://www.draw.io/)

I have tried:

1) Adding routes to each VPN Server[[1]](https://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2008-01/msg00068.html)

Server A

```
sudo route add -net 172.16.200.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.132.52.131 eth1
```

Server B

```
sudo route add -net 172.16.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.132.27.6 eth1
```

Constants:

IP Forwarding enabled on all devices

Client A has a rule to send all packets in .200 subnet to VPN Server A:

```
sudo route add -net 172.16.200.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.100.254
```

Client B has a rule to send all packets in .100 subnet to VPN Server B:

```
 sudo route add -net 172.16.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.200.254
```

If I do a tcpdump I can see the clients sending a ping to their respective VPN server. However, it seems as though it ends there. That is, tcpdump on the other end never shows activity with the exception of an arp response.

Comment: Is ipforwarding enabled on both servers? And what iptables rules does each server have?

Comment: Tell me more about the **private network** between the two servers.  I notice that `10.132.27.6/24` and `10.132.52.131/24` are on different subnets, which almost certainly means there is another router in play somewhere?  You almost certainly need to do something there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your two '10/8' addresses for the private network are on different subnets, there is almost certainly some other device that would also need to be changed.

But one thing you could do is make one or both serversa client to each other.  So instead of trying to do the routing over the private network, you could do all the routing entirely within your OpenVPN configuration.

So on your server 1 you would have a ccd for the 'server 2' client that would push an address like 172.16.100.253 to, and setup routes and iroutes for the 172.16.200.0/24 network.

Bascially this would just be setting 'server 1' as if it was handling a site-to-site connection for the 'server 2' client and networks.

Comment: I second that... I'd try routing all the packets through the external nic.